# <tr> error in Outlook 2010 for PC HTML email

Tags: css, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I am developing an HTMl email for a client. Seems standard and straightforward, and nowhere near complicated. I used nested tables and all of (what I think) are the correct CSS rules and perameters. However, when the email is sent to someone who has Outlook 2009 - 2013 a strange thing happens to the second row of nested tables (see image).

Outlook nested table error

[image]

If I switch the blocks from row 1 to row 2 and so on, the error still occurs. I have thrown hard heights into every `<td>` and all of the necessary inlines, yet I cannot fix the error. It seems no matter what I do that second row breaks.

Does anyone see perhaps something that I do not in my code?

```css
#outlook a{
    padding:0;
}

.ReadMsgBody{
    width:100%;
}

body{
    width:100% !important;
    min-width:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

v*{
    behavior:url(#default#VML);
    display:inline-block;
}

td{
    border-collapse: separate !important;
}

.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div{
    line-height:100%;
}

a img{
    border:none;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

img{
    display:block;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none !important; 
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

table, table td{
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    mso-table-lspace:0pt;
    mso-table-rspace:0pt;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

table[class=full] {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height:1.4em;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:1.4em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrappertable{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100% !important;
    line-height:100% !important;
}

br[class=show]{
    display: none !important;
    max-height: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    mso-hide: all;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    table{
        width:100% !important;
    }

    table[class=content]{
        width:95% !important;
    }

    td[class=hide]{
        display: none !important;
        max-height: 0px !important;
        font-size: 0px !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        mso-hide: all !important;
        width: 0 !important;
    }

    td[class=fullwidth]{
        width:100% !important;
        float:left !important;
    }

    /*replace image with mobile version*/
    td#pic1 img{
        content:url("http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/AP/S9496ROW/images/header-mobile.jpg") !important;
    }

    div[class=height]{
        height: auto !important;
    }

    /*repeat ID as necessary*/
        img[class=fullwidth]{
        width:100% !important;
        height:auto !important;
    }

    img[class=threequarters]{
        float: none !important;
        width: 75% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: auto !important;
    }

    img[class=twothirds]{
        float: none !important;
        width: 66.6666% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: auto !important;
    }

    img[class=halfwidth]{
        float: none !important;
        width: 50% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: auto !important;
    }

    img[class=onethird]{
        width: 33.3333% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: auto !important;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    img[class=quarterwidth]{
        width: 25% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: auto !important;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    img[class=hide]{
        display: none !important;
        max-height: 0px !important;
        font-size: 0px !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        mso-hide: all !important;
        width: 0 !important;
    }

    div[class=fullwidth]{
        max-width: 95% !important;
    }

    p,h1,h2[class=centered]{
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    br[class=show]{
        display: inline !important;
    }

    br[class=hide]{
        display: none !important;
        max-height: 0px;
        font-size: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all;
    }

    span[class=hide]{
        display: none !important;
        max-height: 0px;
        font-size: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all;
    }
}
```

```html
<tr>
                      <td width="718" align="center">
       <!--THIS IS THE CONTENT TABLE-->
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
         <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
           <v:fill type="tile" src="THIS IS YOUR IMAGE PATH" color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </v:background>
         <![endif]-->
                           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="700">
                               <tr>
                                <td align="center"><a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/AP/S9496ROW/images/AP_LPG_BANNER_ENG.png" width="700" height="102" alt="Lowest Price Guarantee" class="fullwidth"/></a>
                             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#1e8de6" style="background-color: #1e8de6">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="content" width="95%" height="70">
           <tr><td colspan="2" height="14" style="line-height: 14px"></td></tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fullwidth">
             <a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/AP/S9496ROW/images/AP-Logo_clear.png" width="250" height="42" alt="Advantage Program" class="twothirds" vspace="10"/></a>
            </td>
            <td class="fullwidth">
             <p style="font-size: 21px; text-align: right; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 32px;" class="centered"><strong>FEATURED</strong> <span style="font-weight: lighter !important">LOCATIONS</span></p>
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr><td colspan="2" height="14" style="line-height: 14px"></td></tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" id="pic1">
          <a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/AP/S9496ROW/images/header.jpg" width="700" height="470" alt="" class="fullwidth"/></a>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center"><br />
          <p style="text-align: center; color: #1e8de6; font-size: 26px; font-weight: light"><font style="color: #1e8de6; text-align: center; font-size: 26px; font-weight: light"><strong>Find your favorite Wyndham and book today!</strong></font></p>
          <br />
         </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
         <td align="center">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="640">
           <tr>
            <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="320">
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center" width="300" valign="top">
   <!--property table--> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300"  style="width: 300px; border: solid 1px #1e8de6; border-radius: 5px;" >
     <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; line-height: 168px;" class="fullwidth" align="center">
      <img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/HLL/testing/Property3.jpg" width="300" height="168" alt="" class="fullwidth" style="display: block !important;"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="60" style="line-height: 60px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 19px; font-weight: lighter; line-height: 24px;">Wyndham Ocean Boulevard</p>
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 19px;">Myrtle Beach, SC</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" class="content">
        <tr>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;"></td>
         <td align="center" valign="top" height="260" style="line-height: 260px !important; height: 260px !important; width: 280px !important; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="280" class="fullwidth">
          <p  style="color: #666666; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px !important; font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif'; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" >A stay at the stylish Wyndham Ocean Boulevard will certainly be one to remember. Enjoy award-winning accommodations and amenities surrounded by gentle waves of North Myrtle Beach. This spectacular high-rise, beachfront property is where retro-flavor meets a stylish, contemporary finish. You will certainly love returning to these one and two private bedroom vacation condos complete with full kitchen, washer and dryer and spacious living areas.</p></td>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="42" style="line-height: 42px;">
       <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#1e8de6">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net"
style="background-color:#1e8de6;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:lighter;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Book Now!</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
 </table>
            </td>
            <td class="fullwidth" align="center">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="320">
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center" width="300" valign="top">
   <!--property table--> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" style="width: 300px; border: solid 1px #1e8de6; border-radius: 5px;" >
     <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 168px; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="fullwidth" align="center">
      <img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/HLL/testing/Property4.jpg" width="300" height="168" alt="" class="fullwidth" style="display: block !important;"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="60" style="line-height: 60px; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 19px; font-weight: lighter; line-height: 24px;">Wyndham Resort at Avon</p>
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 19px;">Avon, Colorado</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" class="content">
        <tr>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;"></td>
         <td align="center" valign="top" height="260" style="line-height: 260px !important; height: 260px !important; width: 280px !important; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="280" class="fullwidth">
          <p  style="color: #666666; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px !important; font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif'; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" >Right in the heart of Rocky Mountain ski country, friendly alpine villages welcome visitors from around the world. Tucked across the Eagle River from Beaver Creek's famous slopes, this resort houses an array of apartment-style suites for up to 10 guests. Each features a full kitchen, fireplace, and private balcony. It's a dreamy place to call home, no matter the time of year.</p></td>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="42" style="line-height: 42px;">
       <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#1e8de6">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net"
style="background-color:#1e8de6;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:lighter;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Book Now!</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
 </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="718" align="center">
       <!--THIS IS THE CONTENT TABLE-->
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
         <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
           <v:fill type="tile" src="THIS IS YOUR IMAGE PATH" color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </v:background>
         <![endif]-->
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="700">
          <tr>
         <td align="center">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="640">
           <tr>
            <td class="fullwidth" align="center"  height="570" valign="top">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="320">
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center" width="300" valign="top">
   <!--property table--> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300"  style="width: 300px; border: solid 1px #1e8de6; border-radius: 5px;" >
     <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 168px;" class="fullwidth" align="center" height="168">
      <img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/HLL/testing/Property1.jpg" width="300" height="168" alt="" class="fullwidth" style="display: block !important;"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="60" style="line-height: 60px;">
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 19px; font-weight: lighter; line-height: 24px;">Wyndham at Waikiki Beach Walk</p>
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 19px;">Waikiki Beach, Hawaii</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" class="content">
        <tr>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important; height: 400px;" height="400">&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="center" valign="top" height="400" style="line-height: 400px !important; height: 400px !important; width: 280px !important; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="280" class="fullwidth">
          <p style="color: #666666; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px !important; font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif'; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" >Wyndham at Waikiki Beach Walk offers a premium location just one block from Oahu's famous Waikiki Beach. Guests have easy access to shopping, dining, and live entertainment. The resort offers guests planned activities, classes, and games for adults, children and families. You will find yourself in a paradise where you can relax on a sandy beach, enjoy swimming in the Pacific Ocean, or find excitement just steps away!</p>
         </td>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important; height:400px;" height="400">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="42" style="line-height: 42px;">
       <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#1e8de6">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net"
style="background-color:#1e8de6;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:lighter;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Book Now!</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
 </table>
            </td>
            <td class="fullwidth" align="center" height="570" valign="top">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="320">
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center" width="300" valign="top">
   <!--property table--> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300"  style="width: 300px; border: solid 1px #1e8de6; border-radius: 5px;" >
     <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-collapse: collapse" class="fullwidth" align="center">
      <img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/HLL/testing/Property2.jpg" width="300" height="168" alt="" class="fullwidth" style="display: block !important;"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="60" style="line-height: 60px;">
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 19px; font-weight: lighter; line-height: 24px;">Wyndham Bonnet Creek Resort</p>
       <p style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 19px;">Orlando, Florida</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" class="content">
        <tr>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important; height:400px;" height="400">&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="center" valign="top" height="400" style="line-height: 400px !important; height: 400px !important; width: 280px !important; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="280" class="fullwidth">
          <p  style="color: #666666; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px !important; font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif'; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" >Located adjacent to Walt Disney World Resort, Wyndham Bonnet Creek Resort is the perfect home base in Lake Buena Vista for all kinds of Orlando adventures, and is just a few minutes' drive to Universal Orlando Resort and Wet 'n Wild. Guests have a blast with all the fun and exciting activities available at Wyndham Bonnet Creek Resort, designed to enhance family vacations with unexpected pleasures.</p></td>
         <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" height="42" style="line-height: 42px;">
       <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.advantageprogram.net" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#1e8de6">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.advantageprogram.net"
style="background-color:#1e8de6;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:lighter;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Book Now!</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td style="height: 20px; line-height: 20px;" height="20"></td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td width="10" style="width: 10px !important;" align="center">&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px;" height="10" colspan="3"></td></tr>
 </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="718" align="center">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="700">
        <tr>
         <td align="center">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
           <tr><td height="25" style="line-height: 25px;"></td></tr>
           <tr>
            <td align="center">
             <p style="font-size: 28px; text-align: center; color: #666666;">Promo Code: <span style="color: #1e8de6; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold">S9496ROW</span></p>
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr><td height="25" style="line-height: 25px;"></td></tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#1e8de6" style="background-color: #1e8de6">
         <img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/AP/S9496ROW/images/numbers.png" width="550" height="118" alt="" class="fullwidth"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#1e8de6" style="background-color: #1e8de6">
          <a href="mailto:service@advantageprogram.net?subject=Now Available! Wherever you want to be, Wyndham is there! Book Now! Code: S9496ROW"><img src="http://www.immediatefill.com/SendyImages/AP/S9496ROW/images/email.png" width="350" height="45" alt="email: Service@Advantageprogram.net" class="fullwidth"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td height="10" style="line-height: 10px;"></td></tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" >
          <p style="font-size:11px; color:#626262; line-height: 22px;">Advantage Program &bull;&nbsp;P.O. Box 35076&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;Las Vegas, NV 89133-5076&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;USA</p>  
          <p><a href="[unsubscribe]" title="Unsubscribe" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:11px; color:#626262;  line-height: 22px;">Unsubscribe from this list</a></p>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: it's seems to be that outlook client has his own html browser and surprise, not working fine. Options: Use image html to image) and send the image. Reduce the complex of the html, remove lines. Use a third software, check this https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

Comment: I think you so much for your suggestion and yes, since I had a deadline I did use images. However I would still like to figure this out to reduce the number of images in my email anyway.

Comment: check then the version of the client that read the html to hide the email and show a link, tipical you're mail client doesn't support ... cool way